# Chrome extension - insertCSS onUpdated event

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to insert css on tab when she's update, but it won't works... No css affect the tab, but when I launch my function onClicked, it works perfectly.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
  if(changeInfo.status == 'complete'){
    cssInject(tab);
  }
});

function cssInject(tab){
  chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {
      file: "css/mycss.css"
  });
}
```

Comment: What permissions do you declare in the manifest ?

Comment: "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],

Comment: Damned, you're right. This is only an issue of permission. Now it's working perfectly ! Thanx

Comment: Please, consider posting the answer to this problem (and marking it as accepted), so users landing on this page facing a similar problem will be able to spot it easily (without having to read through the comments).

Comment: What's the answer to this question?

Comment: Oh - I guess the permission missing is "tabs".  I'm facing a similar issue, but I already have that permission, so I'll post a separate question.